# Update 1 Sum + Value SQL Server vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two columns in my table (`ID` and `Auto`); when I click the button 1+, I want to increase the value in column `auto`.

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Table_8 SET ID = @ID,Auto = @Auto WHERE ID = @ID")
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Auto+1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = +1

cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need second parameter @Auto You can simply do it in Query

And the second thing is, why is the auto column in your DB `VARCHAR` it may need to `INT` if you want to perform Increment like operation on It.

I recommend you to change otherwise you need to convert that value in integer to perform addition.

Please try below code after change column:

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn        
cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Table_8 SET Auto = Auto+1 WHERE ID = @ID")
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1"      
cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Or:

```vb
cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Table_8 SET Auto =CAST((CAST(Auto AS INT)+1) AS VARCHAR(your size)) WHERE ID = @ID")
```

Comment: dear i  have two forms one is form1 and second is form2 i want when i click on the button then form1 will close and form2 show plz send the coding

Comment: @khan46, that question is completely unrelated so it doesn't belong on this page at all, never mind in a comment. If you have a new question then post a new question, with all the appropriate information, including what you have already tried.  "I want to do X, send code" is not a question for SO.

Comment: There's no point setting the `ID` column to the value of `@ID` when the `WHERE` clause has already established that is it's current value.

Comment: click this link and check   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113899/form1-close-form2-show-in-vb-net

Comment: @khan46 Please accept FrustratedDeveloper's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. That is the best way to say Thank you on Stack Overflow.